# Access AppResources or ResourceManager from scheduled task agent

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to access `AppResources` from a scheduled task agent to get localized strings.

But I can't access it using `AppResources`. From a scheduled task agent, it throws an error

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

The Exception message is

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "MyApp.Resources.AppResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "ScheduledTaskAgent1" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

I'm totally lost here. There is quite no answer on the internet, or no "how to". I think I mixed up some imports in my `ScheduledTaskAgent` project...

Comment: Did you happen to move your classes to a different namespace lately? it could be that the designer didn't update the latest location of your Resource file

Comment: Can you provide some code how you are accessing AppResources?